# Reuse single Xib in storyboard iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiview

I want to load an **Xib** in storyboad's `UIVIEW` that would be a child view such that in a view controller I dragged a `UIVIEW` now I want to load a Xib in that, how can I do that?

I'vent much experience in Xib's so it is difficuilt for me to load an Xib in storyboard's UIView.

However, my case is that, I created a custom `Xib` that contains some `UILABELs` and `UIIMAGES`, and I want to load in Storyboard's `UIVIEWCONTROLLERs` that are multiple. I want to reuse a single Xib in mulitple storyboard's `VIEWCONTROLLER`. Initially I just created a `Xib`.

My question is, how can I reuse that `Xib` in `storyboard's` `UIVIEWCONTROLLER's` `UIVIEW` so that I can say that a reusability.